# Tridion Sites 9.5 Access Management with Windows Idp Update and Delete actions not working

Tags: sites-9.5, access-management

One of our customers, We did install Tridion Sites 9.5 Acces Management Service in IIS and configured Windows Idp and then we were able to add the Windows Idp provider and able to log in and everything was worked as expected.

After a few days, later customer noticed and complained, In the Tridion Acces Management update and delete actions are not working. We were not able to modify or remove any claim roles. but log in to Access Management was working fine.

There were no errors in the access management log files, We only saw the error message in the UI as highlighted in the image.

```
Error message: Failed to delete user(id:5). Generic Error
```

[image]
[image]

After further investigation and found that the request failed to load resources and responded with a status code 405 (Method Not Allowed) in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was related to ASP.NET Core with IIS - HTTP Verb Not Allowed. In the ASP.NET Core application enabling the **WebDAVModule** module does not allow **PUT** and **DELETE** requests.

This issue has been resolved by updating the Access Management **web.config** file to remove **WebDAVModule**.

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Good find, @Velu. Will there be a hotfix or update to the default Access Management web.config, perhaps? :-)

Comment: It doesn't need HF, It depends on where you install your access management service, if you install it separate server better not to enable the **WebDAVModule** feature in IIS. In most of my previous installations, I have never seen this issue because I have not installed this WebDAVModule IIS feature.